# Where is the source code of Mono?

Tags: mono

For example, I want to find the source code of IEnumerable, but it is not in

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System/System.Collections.Generic

So where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the GitHub repository and pressed T to activate the file finder and then typed in IEnumerable and one of the search results was:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/IEnumerable.cs

Answer (score 0):

@MattWard already pointed out the key.

I just want to inform you that not all System.* classes are in System.dll, even for Microsoft .NET. If you go to MSDN you can see clearly that [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined in mscorlib.dll, which maps to "corlib" in Mono.

This tip applies to other classes as well.